# Kentico 13 Smart Search not working with Local Indexes

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-13

We are implementing Smart Search in Kentico 13. In our initial we had enabled the search feature, followed by adding local indexes (I added a local index with name "DefaultSearchIndex"). For the indexes we have set the path to a page with sub pages so that search results are considered from sub pages. After doing the configuration when I search from the admin panel under Local Indexes>DefaultSearchIndex>Search preview, I get the correct result.

Now, the issue I am facing is that I want to use the same index at controller end to return a custom view. Here I used the code provided in documentation also shown below

`
IEnumerable<string> searchIndexes = new List<string> { "DefaultSearchIndex" };

```
            int pageNumber = 1;
            int pageSize = 1000;
            UserInfo searchUser = MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser;
            string cultureCode = "en-us";
            /* Indicates whether the search service uses site default language version of pages as a replacement
            for pages that are not translated into the language specified by 'cultureCode' */
            bool combineWithDefaultCulture = true;

            // Prepares a 'SearchParameters' object to search through indexes of the 'Pages' type
            SearchParameters searchParameters = SearchParameters.PrepareForPages(searchQuery, searchIndexes, pageNumber, pageSize, searchUser, cultureCode, combineWithDefaultCulture);


            searchParameters.Path = searchPath.Replace("/", "") + "/%";

            // Searches the specified indexes
            SearchResult searchResult = SearchHelper.Search(searchParameters);`
```

You can see that I have added the index but when I call this API, this is not returning any results using the index name of the local index.

Secondly, when I rename the Local Index to "Search", this returns the results but for all the nodes, that is it is not considering the selected path in the Indexed content.

I was expecting correct results from the selected path.

Answer (score 0):

Try hardcoding the exact path you want in `searchParameters.Path` with using the first index you mention.

```
searchParameters.Path = "/my-path/%";
```

That should validate if filtering down the results of the index by path works or not.

Comment: Thanks, But I want it to be searched from index name, As I have plenty of paths based on  different conditions. So, want this to be done dynamically.